# Google place auto-complete api sort the result by location

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geo

I am using google api "place auto-complete" to show the address suggestions based on user's input. My rest api call is as below. It's returning me the results but in a random order. I want to sort the result based on the distance from given location. Is there a parameter to specify that in request or how can i do that? (i don't want to use google place search api as i just need it for auto-complete.)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter to order places autocomplete results by the distance from the given point.

I can see that somebody has already filed this feature request in Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65241727

Feel free to add a comment on the feature request to explain your use case and star the feature request to add your vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is method I use to get more relevant results on Google Autocomplete API.

1. Set "location" and "origin" parameters to the user location.
2. Set radius to 500

This does not limit the request but prioritizes the response based on the user location.

You can also increase the relevancy further by sorting the "distance_meters" field on the response.